# C# Regex.Replace does not replace

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I've got a little problem for you geniuses.

I have tested a pattern with "RegexLab" for replacing/filtering text. It worked perfectly there, but my code didn't do well.

**Pattern:**

```
<li>(.*?)<ul>.*?</ul>
```

**Replacement**

```
<li>$1
```

**Input:**

```
<b>Title</b>\n<br/>\n<ul><li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>\n<b>Title</b><br/>\n<ul><li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>
```

**What the output should be like:**

```
<b>Title</b>\n<br/>\n<ul><li>Text\n</li>\n<li>Text\n</li>\n<li>Text\n</li>\n<li>Text\n</li>\n<li>Text\n</li>\n<li>Text\n</li>\n</ul>\n<b>Title</b><br/>\n<ul><li>Text\n</li>\n<li>Text\n</li>\n<li>Text\n</li>\n<li>Text\n</li>\n<li>Text\n</li>\n</ul>
```

**My code:**

```
string filteredText = Regex.Replace(Input, Pattern, Replacement);
```

**Problem:**

My output is wrong, I don't get the filtered text, I get the whole unfiltered Input. RegexLab shows me that everything is right.

**Whole code (will look dirty here)**

```
           string input = "<b>Title</b>\n<br/>\n<ul><li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>\n<b>Title</b><br/>\n<ul><li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n<li><b>Text</b>\n<ul><li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n<li>Trash</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>";
        string pattern = @"<li>(.*?)<ul>.*?</ul>";
        string replacement = "<li>$1";
        string filteredText = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

**Working code in PHP (needed in C#):**

```
preg_replace("/<li>(.*?)<ul>.*?<\/ul>/s",'<li>$1',$input);
```

I need a solution without HtmlAgilityPack!

Comment: Maybe it's time to switch to e.g. the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), rather than trying to mangle this all through regular expressions.

Comment: It works in PHP, but I also want it to work in C#.

Comment: The pattern in your code sample doesn't match the one in your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My mistake. Copied wrong pattern there.

Comment: @user3319473 have you checked the `RegexOptions`? Perhaps PHP has different default options than .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

You need to have the interpreter to see to whole string as a single line text, otherwise `.` (dot) will not match the `\n` (line feed)

Comment: Note that the SingleLine option is also specified on the original PHP regex with the `/s` switch at the end of the pattern. In .Net you could write it as `(?s)<li>(.*?)<ul>.*?</ul>` too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#options